# How do i run zone (zone-when-idle) for all windows?

Tags: buffers, window, games

[Zone Mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ZoneMode) is awesome

But when I run it using `M-x zone`, or by setting `zone-when-idle` variable it starts animating only one(selected) window.

Is there any way to run it for all windows?

Comment: As far as I can see this is not a very low hanging fruit since zone is very focused on the current window.  One way could be to display the same zonery in every window and remember the state of each window when zone starts.

Comment: Good idea, but I think, displaying the same zone everywhere could be done easier. For example, I can open their default `*zone*` buffer in every window, then execute `(zone)` so it will modify this buffer(which is displayed in all windows). At the end, when the zone is interrupted it kills own buffer which will cause all windows to revert to their previous state. Should work, right?

Comment: AFAICT the call to zone is blocking. I encourage you to try something anyway.

Comment: @OlesSavluk Have you come up with a solution for this? I'd be interested in this too.